# axistools-maven-plugin wsdl2java how to set different packages for each wsdl

Tags: web-services, package, maven-plugin, axis, wsdl2java

I want use the axistools-maven-plugin to generate java classes from wsdl.

Now I have this code and it works:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>ax-ws-autogen</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</sourceDirectory>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>myfirstwsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <packageSpaces>my.package.code.first</packageSpaces>
                <testCases>false</testCases>
                <serverSide>false</serverSide>
                <subPackageByFileName>false</subPackageByFileName>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now I need to use another wsdl. So I want add it to this plugin, but in another packages. How can I to do?

I see that I can add wsdl file in `<wsdlFiles>` tag, but I don't know how to add the new package for the new wsdl.

With CXF I can set different wsdl and packages in the `<wsdlOptions>` tag, but with axis I don't know how to do.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem setting `<subPackageByFileName> = true` and changing `<packageSpace>` in a general package:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>ax-ws-autogen</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</sourceDirectory>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>myfirstwsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    <wsdlFile>mysecondwsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <packageSpace>my.package.code</packageSpace>
                <testCases>false</testCases>
                <serverSide>false</serverSide>
                <subPackageByFileName>true</subPackageByFileName>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In this way I get a single package ***my.package.code*** that contain two packages:

- *my.package.code.myfirstwsdl* with all classes of my first wsdl;
- *my.package.code.mysecondwsdl* with all classes of my second wsdl.